Azure cmake can't find Ninja
In order to help learn Azure pipeline builds, I am attempting to migrate a GitHub Action to Azure Windows-2022 yml. I've gone through and have several Linux builds now working on Azure. This is for windows, and once I get it working, I get to try macOS builds.
The error first:
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja". 
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.

The azure-pipeline.yml file:
- job: mingw
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-2022
  # bash?
  steps:
  - checkout: self
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '3.8'
      addToPath: true
  - bash: |
      curl -LO https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/releases/download/v1.10.2/ninja-win.zip
      mkdir -p C:/ninja
      unzip -q ninja-win.zip -d C:/ninja
      export PATH="/c/ninja:$PATH"
      which ninja
      ls -la /c/ninja
    displayName: 'Install Ninja'

  - bash: |
      C:/msys64/usr/bin/pacman -Sy --noconfirm --needed mingw-w64-x86_64-uasm
      export GITHUB_PATH="/c/msys64/mingw64/bin:$GITHUB_PATH"
      export PATH="/c/msys64/mingw64/bin:$PATH"
      C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/uasm -?
    displayName: Install UASM
  - bash: |
      cmake -S. -B build \
      -D UPDATE_DEPS=ON \
      -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
      -D BUILD_WERROR=ON \
      -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/c/ninja/ninja \
      -G Ninja
    displayName: 'Configure CMake'
  - bash: cmake --build build
    displayName: CMake build Build
  - bash: cmake --install build --prefix /tmp
    displayName: CMake Install Build

The output from:
which ninja
ls -la /c/ninja

Is:
/c/ninja/ninja
total 540
drwxr-xr-x 1 VssAdministrator 197121      0 Apr 18 02:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 VssAdministrator 197121      0 Apr 18 02:15 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 VssAdministrator 197121 538112 Nov 28  2020 ninja.exe

So we know ninja exists.
When a similiar pipeline runs on GitHub Actions, it all just works, but I'd really like to get this working on Azure. This is the equivalent on GitHub Actions that works:
    mingw:
      runs-on: windows-2022
      defaults:
        run:
          shell: bash
      steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        - uses: actions/setup-python@v5
          with:
            python-version: '3.8'
        - uses: lukka/get-cmake@latest
        - name: Setup uasm
          run: |
            C:/msys64/usr/bin/pacman -Sy --noconfirm --needed mingw-w64-x86_64-uasm
            printf '%s\n' 'C:/msys64/mingw64/bin' >> $GITHUB_PATH
        - name: UASM Check
          run: uasm -?
        - run: |
            cmake -S. -B build \
            -D UPDATE_DEPS=ON \
            -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
            -D BUILD_WERROR=ON \
            -G Ninja
        - run: cmake --build build
        - run: cmake --install build --prefix /tmp

I've tried for this line -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/c/ninja/ninja \ to use:
-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/c/ninja/ninja.exe \

and I've tried add it before cmake like:
export CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/c/ninja/ninja

as well as moving -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM to different places in the order of the cmake command.
So far, nothing has worked. I don't have a self-hosted Windows agent so I can't play with this locally, which is making this really tough and slow to debug. Spent several hours trying everything I can find online, but no go. I'm thinking the solution is probably something tiny that I was unaware of about cmake.

In your GitHub Actions, cannot see any step to install ninja.

Someone in our group wrote the original GitHub Actions yaml, and it runs well on GitHub windows images as shown. I'd assume Ninja is installed by default on GitHub images?  For Linux builds we use lukka/get-cmake@latest which I believe has Ninja included.

In Azure pipeline, each Bash task has a separate session to run the commands/script set on the task. And the session will be closed when the task is completed.
The environment variables set/updated by the 'export' command seem are only available in the session of current task and not for that of the subsequent tasks.
To let the environment variables can be available for the subsequent tasks, you can use the logging command "SetVariable" to set/update them. See below example as reference.
    steps:
    . . .

    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Install Ninja'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          installDir="C:/ninja"
          curl -LO https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/releases/download/v1.10.2/ninja-win.zip
          mkdir -p $installDir
          unzip -q ninja-win.zip -d $installDir
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH]$installDir;$(PATH)"
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM]$installDir/ninja.exe"


This seems convoluted, which makes me wonder if I am approaching this entirely wrong? Going to try your suggestion and if it works great. Since I am just learning, I am hoping there is an easier way to approach builds on windows. Especially since this is one of 6 builds in the yaml, some with a matrix of builds.

@OutofControl, Okay. Go ahead to try with it.

Yes, this worked and that job completed successfully! There are just so many docs, and I have never been one to be able to read from A-Z, but I can see the benefit :) Thank you helping.  For others seeing this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts
